# What is meant by IEnumerator and yield in C#, Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, c#-4.0, unity-container

here is the piece of code from my app. I want to know why these keywords used and what is there functionality in this specific scenario:

Keywords: yield, IEnumerator

```
IEnumerator CoCheckWord(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (3.5f);
         .
         .
         .  
         .    
 }
```

Comment: `code from my app` .. how can it be your app without you knowing what it does? O.o

Answer (score 1):

That is a Coroutine. You can read more about them [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). The general gist of it is that you are able to create asynchronous code in Unity by using them. What `yield return` does is stop executing the function until whatever you passed in returns. So 'yield return new WaitForSeconds (3.5f);' will essentially wait for 3.5 seconds and then continue executing the code after that. With this you are able to easily create delayed functions as well as functions that are executed over multiple frames. Again, I strongly recommend you have a read through the Coroutines page in the [manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) and the [scripting reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html).